# JQuery mobile - dynamically added popup not popping up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have this function which takes a text string such as "Hello there, my name is ¬¬¬John¬¬¬" and the function is trying to output the text surrounded by '¬¬¬' in a button with a pop-up attached with a list of menu options, however, while the button appears ok, is styled properly and shows the link when hovered over, the popup ul list doesn't appear when clicking on it.  The whole function is below for context (obviously most of it is probably irrelevant to the question).  I would really appreciate some help because I have searched around for a while for answers:

```
function displayText( element, txt )
{
    console.log("lesson text:" + txt);
    var buildtext = '<span>';

    if(txt.indexOf("¬¬¬") != -1)     
    {
        var splitarr = txt.split("¬¬¬");

        for (var i=0;i<splitarr.length;i++)
        {   

            if( i%2 == 1 ) 
            {
                buildtext += '<a href="#fwordPopupMenu' + i + '" data-rel="fwordPopup" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="slideup" data-icon="false" data-theme="e">' + splitarr[i] + '</a>' +
                              '<div data-role="popup" id="fwordPopupMenu' + i + '" data-theme="d">' +
                               '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;" data-theme="d">' +
                                '<li><a href="#">View details</a></li>' +
                               '</ul>' +
                              '</div>';
            }
                else
            {
                buildtext += splitarr[i];
            }                        
            console.log(splitarr[i]);
        }
        buildtext += '</span>';
    }
    else    // text contains no special words so display as is
    {
        buildtext = txt;
    }

    $(element).html(buildtext);

    if( element == '#tutor-paragraph' )
    {
        //document.getElementById("tutor-paragraph").style.webkitAnimationName = "";
        console.log("reseting animation");
        $('#tutor-paragraph').addClass('run-animation');
        //document.getElementById("tutor-paragraph").style.webkitAnimationName = "example";
    }
    //refresh element to get styling
    $(element).trigger('create');
    //$('element').selectmenu('refresh', true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build the link, change

```
data-rel="fwordPopup"
```

to

```
data-rel="popup"
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/WKXu4/)**

Comment: Thank-you!  Very well spotted - I was thinking it was probably a really technical issue or something but it turns out it was quite a silly mistake by me..